# Strategy In auction bidding

Tags: game-theory

I was at an auction recently where three autograph signatures of Marilyn Monroe were up for auction, not as a single lot, but in three separate lots. The three lots were virtually identical, and all had the same opening bid amount ($1000). Assuming the number of interested bidders is unknown, but greater than three, what is the best bidding strategy for acquiring one of them at the lowest price?

Comment: Are you or the other bidders allowed to collude (to act together through a secret understanding, especially with evil or harmful intent)?

Comment: Are you assuming that the three separate lots are auctioned one at a time, that is, the bidding for one lot starts and ends before the bidding for another lot starts and ends?  Or is there an overlap of bidding times?

Comment: Can a bidder bid on the three lots at the same time?  Also, once a bidder wins a lot, will he or she no longer bid on the remaining lots?

Comment: Are the bids public (known to the other bidders) or are they sealed? May a bidder bid more than once per lot?

Comment: Do the bidders have a maximum amount for bidding?  If so, do these amounts differ?  Are these amounts known to all the bidders?

Comment: Can the bidders be identified?  That is, if the bids are public, and you see a bid, can you say who among the bidders made it?

Comment: There is no colluding between bidders. The lots are auctioned one at a time, with no overlap. No one can bid on all three (or even two) at a time. No sealed bids. Anyone can bid more than once on any lot, as in any auction. Each bidder probably has a maximum amount in mind, but no one else knows what it is. One bidder could try to acquire two or three, but let's assume that to be unlikely.

Comment: The bidders can usually be identified unless the auction room is huge, but I don't see how that makes a difference.

Comment: Actually, there are some auctions (sealed bids) where sometimes only one bid per bidder per lot is allowed.  Also, if you know the maximum amount a certain bidder can make, and the maximum amounts of the bidders differ, then it does make a difference if you know who made a bid.

Comment: [Auction theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auction_theory) is more of an economics topic, but unfortunately an [Economics StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) proposal didn't work out.

Answer (score 3):

No answer is possible without much more information.  In particular, your objective is not well-defined, nor do we know the objectives of the other bidders.

Comment: My objective is to acquire one of the three at the lowest price, and that is also the objective of the other bidders.

Comment: @JacobSteiner, exactly one of the three, or at least one of the three?

Comment: The two parts of your objective are in conflict.  At the lowest possible price, the probability of acquiring a lot is nearly $0$. If you bid more, you will increase the probability of acquiring one, but it will not be at the lowest possible price. There is a tradeoff.  You have not given us any information that might allow us to resolve this.

Comment: I shouldn't have said "lowest possible price."  Better is "lowest cost to me."

Comment: Assume the purest  possible situation - not seeing any other bidding paddles, no colluding, no known maximums, etc. is this one for John Forbes Nash?

Comment: You still haven't addressed the problem.  Let's take a simple situation.  Suppose you know for sure that a bid of $x$ will get you the last lot, and nothing lower will.  You can either take it or leave it.  What do you do?  Presumably there is some maximum $x$ that you would be willing to spend.  But you haven't told us what this is.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert Israel points out, you'll need to specify the conditions.  For example, let's say that all the other bidders have a maximum amount that they can bid per lot, and you know that the maximum among these is $B_{max}$.  If you have unlimited money, and your goal is to acquire at least one of the lots at the "lowest price," then simply bid $B_{max}+2$ on the first two lots, then bid $B_{max}+1$ on the third lot.  If this is not what you had in mind, then you should specify the conditions that you are thinking of.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the answer above before I saw your comments in the main post.

Comment: One never knows what the other bidders' maximums are. All I know is my own maximum. But mustn't there be an optimal strategy?

Comment: Actually, sometimes it is possible to know what another bidder's maximum amount is.  For example, a piece of office equipment is being auctioned and the other bidder represents a government organization with a limited budget for that equipment (sometimes this amount is publicly known).